# Getting Sku of bundle-product options in carts/mine/items

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, bundle-product

Suppose I added one bundle product in cart.When I call `\carts\mine\items`,it show respnse of bundle options

```
"extension_attributes": {
        "bundle_options": [{
            "option_id": 643,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [704]
            }, {
            "option_id": 644,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [705]
            }, {
            "option_id": 645,
            "option_qty": 1,
            "option_selections": [706]
            }]
        }
```

Can I get sku of bundle option also?

Please suggest me.

Comment: I've done a lot with bundles in 2.1 but I need a bit more to go on.. What are you trying to do, are you looking for the info in js or PHP, etc. Please describe your question more extensively.

Comment: I want to sku in response of /carts/mines/items api .

Comment: tell me anyone....................

Comment: writing as we speak

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so first things first. We need to find where things are happening. I searched the vendor/magento folder for `carts/mine/items` and that came up with `module-quote/etc/webapi.xml`. Which shows that `Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface` and `getList` is what is used for the output.

The interface we found obviously doesn't return anything, but Magento tends to preference them somewhere with a class, so a quick search turned up `module-quote/etc/di.xml` which has `<preference for="Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface" type="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository" />` in it.

And now we're talking! This `Reposity` class implements the `getList`. Though it doesn't actually show us anything useful in regards to the options for bundles. However, that method does show us this: `$item = $this->getCartItemOptionsProcessor()->addProductOptions($item->getProductType(), $item);`.

From that it's reasonable to deduct that there's a product type specific options processor. Our type is a bundle, so we take a look in `module-bundle` and there it is! `Model/CartItemProcessor.php`.

In that class there's a `processOptions` method which seems to be the place where we want to work.

So, we create a fresh module of our own and create a Plugin:

```
<type name="Magento\Bundle\Model\CartItemProcessor">
    <plugin name="my_module_sku_in_bundle_cart_output"
            type="My\Module\Plugin\BundleCartItemProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

And then in our Plugin file (`My\Module\Plugin\BundleCartItemProcessor`):

```
class BundleCartItemProcessor
{
    public function afterprocessOptions($subject, $result)
    {
        /**
         * @var Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $result
         * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\CartItemProcessor $subject
         */

        $extensionAttributes = $result->getProductOption()->getExtensionAttributes();

        // here is where you go through the result of extensionAttributes
        // and load up the bundle selectionsCollection
        // which you can then use to find the associated
        // product and it's sku. You can then add that
        // sku to the result.

        return $result;
    }
}
```

*If I have time later I might implement the actual solution, but this should get you there, I think.*

Comment: Please provide me implemented solution @Rian